# Keras get_weights() does not return all weights

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I have the following NN:

```
cc = Input(shape=(3,))

dd = Dense(1,activation='tanh')(cc)

dense_model3 = Model(inputs=cc, outputs=dd)

# Compile 
dense_model3.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

dense_model3.fit(copstage3,y_stage9, batch_size=150, epochs=100)

ypredi3 = dense_model3.predict(copstage3,batch_size=150, steps = None)
```

and when I use `dense_model3.get_weights()` ,I get :

```
     ([array([[0.15411839],
     [1.072346  ],
     [0.37893268]], dtype=float32), array([-0.13432428], dtype=float32)]
```

However ,as I have 150 rows in my data ,I would expect 150 different weights, representing each row. What am I missing?

Comment: the shape of `w` is `(3, 1)` and the shape of bias is `(1, )`. This is exactly what you have. The weights are independent of batch size.

Answer (score 0):

Your model has input of size 3,

```
cc = Input(shape=(3,))
```

And output of size 1,

```
dd = Dense(1,activation='tanh')(cc)
```

There are no intermediate layers. So weights are associated with three inputs and one output as given.

```
([array([[0.15411839],
 [1.072346  ],
 [0.37893268]], dtype=float32), array([-0.13432428], dtype=float32)]
```

Where

`[array([[0.15411839], [1.072346  ], [0.37893268]], dtype=float32)`

represents weights of input layer of size three and

```
array([-0.13432428], dtype=float32)
```

represents weights of output layer of size one.

150 rows of data is used to train this layer and after training, the weights are associated to each individual neuron or node.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But, if that is the case ,then I would expect the following: X1*W1+X2*W2+X3*W3 +Bias= Y_Pred. But I get a different result. Any ideas why?

Comment: Output_layer_1 =  X1*W1+X2*W2+X3*W3 +Bias is the output of first layer.

So in your case, this is,

Output_of_Layer_1 = 0.15411839*X1 + 1.072346*X2 + 0.37893268*X3

Y_Pred = -0.13432428*Output_of_Layer_1

Where -0.13432428 is weight of the output node.

I guess you are confused between output node weight and output node value. Both are two different things. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry ,but this doesn't add up... In my example Bias=-0.13432428 ,right? So ,how can you both add the Bias on the output of Layer one ,and then multiply the Bias again with the result? Can you clarify? Perhaps I need to use the Activation function in order to get the same result Keras provides? Thanks

Comment: No. Bias is not -0.1342428. -0.13432428 is the value of the weight of Output node ie in your case, dd. Weights are given from Keras as, weights = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]. 

Where as, bias is given by, biases = model.layers[0].get_weights()[1]. I suggest you get those values and calculate again.

Comment: I get a "list index out of range" error from  model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]... any idea why?